# How can I use a static model with a form reducer in React?

Tags: reactjs, model, state, reduce

The main problem is that developers can add anything they want to standard form reducers state, it isn't static. This leads to a state that is more difficult to comprehend across different developers and basically a hidden model.

I initially created a key/value JS object to represent the data model of the form. I then realized one can only send it to the reducer via the state prop while the reducer returns a new state that contain anything. There is no safety preventing the developer from returning {null} or other crazy things.

I would want the reducer to fail with a console warning if the developer tries to add a state variable to the reducer that isn't defined and initialized in the model. I feel its certainly possible with classes but functions and hooks I'm not sure.

```
export const FormModel = {
  submit: false,
}

export default function FormReducer(state = FormModel, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'submit':
      return { ...state, submit:  action.payload}
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const Form = ({}) => {
  return (
    <form>{/*TODO*/}</form>
  )
}

export default Form

Form.propTypes = {
  //TODO
}
```

Bonus Points: Best way to integrate ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Here I want to talk about one thing that might be similar to what you are looking for.

I created my app using react with typescript and eslint. First, I define a model with the name `IProfileState`, and then I extend to `initialState`.

Like this:

```
interface IProfileState {
    name: string
    age: number
}

interface IState {
    profile: IProfileState
}

const initialState: IState = {
    profile: {
        name: '',
        age: 2
    }
};
```

And I pass `IProfileState` interface to `PayloadAction`, which is the type of redux action, like this.

```
export const uiSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'ui',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setUserProfile: (state, action: PayloadAction<IProfileState>) => {
            state.profile = action.payload;
        }
    }
});
```

And when I trying to enter something wrong or I not define it first on `IProfileState`.

I will get an error like this:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{ name: string; age: number; gender: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IProfileState'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'gender' does not exist in type 'IProfileState'.
    12 |             name: 'doe',
    13 |             age: 10,
  > 14 |             gender: 'male'
       |             ^^^^^^^^^^
    15 |         }));
    16 |     };
```

Maybe you can also implement this. full documentation here https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-TypeScript

Comment: Its interesting. I'm noticing that a lot of the form controls we use seem to require a useState anyway, they don't seem to work the same with formDispath and reducer state reading. I'm also trying to get a grasp at when to use a reducer vs. useState vs. context vs. redux. The options are great, but you start having 100 devs mixing them in uncoordinated ways you end up with the worst-of-all-worlds. I'd really just like to be able to define a static model and update its values at will along with state, tried putting useStates in hash tables at one point, lol. surprised it works like this.

Comment: Emm.. Actually I just use redux for save a global state, like user profile or login state `{ loggedIn: true }`. Where is can read by some pages, and I think useState can't handle that easly.

Comment: Agreed, if your using functions and state, only option is proppassing to get it where it's need. A reducer can be used anywhere, same for context and redux. But I'm surprised there is no static model in react, and 3rd party models can't be integrated. Seems the closest thing is the reducer initializer... there has to be a way to do this in this framework, I'm so surprised. Basically what I'm asking for is no different than a typing system, but seems impossible to implement in herarchical state object... maybe I can put a function at top of reducer to compare to static model before case stmt.